# Date Formula with values of a picklist

Tags: salesforce

I need to create a formula for a date field.
The formula for the new date field id

***New date field=Old Date Field+No of months***

The Number of months comes from a picklist.

Answer (score 1):

This simple requirement exposes some limitations in salesforce's formula language. I.e., The formula below (based on [this](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000BrQ2AAK)) will work, but it's incredibly inelegant and just barely fits in the allowed script size. Hopefully someone else has a better solution.

```
DATE(
    year(BaseDate) + floor((month(BaseDate) + Add_Months__c)/12) 
        + if(and(month(BaseDate)=12,Add_Months__c>=12),-1,0),

    if( mod( month(BaseDate) + Add_Months__c , 12 ) = 0, 12 , mod( month(BaseDate) + Add_Months__c , 12 )),

    min(
        day(BaseDate),
        case(
            max( 
                mod( 
                    month(BaseDate) + Add_Months__c , 12 
                ) , 
                1
            ),
            9,30,
            4,30,
            6,30,
            11,30,
            2,28,
            31
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be very difficult to do (if not impossible) pulling the value directly from the picklist.  Apparently, converting a picklist value to a number causes a significant size increase.  The following formula, *would* do what you want

```
DATE(
    FLOOR((MONTH(CalcDate__c) + VALUE(TEXT(AddMonths__c))) / 12) + YEAR(CalcDate__c),
    MOD((MONTH(CalcDate__c) + VALUE(TEXT(AddMonths__c))), 12),
    1) + (DAY(CalcDate__c) - 1)
```

Where `CalcDate__c` is the original date and `AddMonths__c` is your picklist.

The formula does come with the caveat that, it will sometimes roll into the next month (for example, adding 1 month to 3/31/2011 will yield 5/1/2011 instead of 4/30/2011).  If you need to get around this, you could use `CASE` statements as in Jeremy's answer.

The other issue with the formula is that it, unfortunately, is **5.7k** characters which exceeds the 5k maximum.

You can avoid this, however, by first creating a workflow rule which copies the picklist value into a hidden number field and then use the following formula which has a compiled size of **1.9k**:

```
DATE(
    FLOOR((MONTH(CalcDate__c) + AddMonths2__c) / 12) + YEAR(CalcDate__c),
    MOD((MONTH(CalcDate__c) + AddMonths2__c), 12),
    1) + (DAY(CalcDate__c) - 1)
```

In this case, `AddMonths2__c` is your numeric copy of `AddMonths__c`.

This formula will save in Salesforce and should achieve what you are trying to do (although it does have the same end-of-month roll over as the first formula)

Comment: Thanks Zack I think your idea works for me.@Jeremy I will keep yours in use it somewhere else.